# How to find biggest table in each tablespace in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I create following SQL statement but it show me biggest tables in general. I want to see it for each tablespace.

```
select tablespace_name, max(BYTES/1024/1024), SEGMENT_NAME 
from dba_segments 
where SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE' 
group by tablespace_name,SEGMENT_NAME,tablespace_name
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have tablespace_name twice in the GROUP BY. Remove the latter one.

Comment: Thanks to all for your fast respond. I find solution my self but will check yours too.

Comment: select t1.tablespace_name,t1.mb/1024/1024,t2.segment_name from (select tablespace_name,max(BYTES) as mb from dba_segments where SEGMENT_TYPE='TABLE'  group by tablespace_name )  t1
  inner join dba_segments t2
  on t1.mb =t2.BYTES
  where t2.segment_type='TABLE'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it shorter when you use [FIRST](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions074.htm#SQLRF00641) function:

```
SELECT tablespace_name, MAX(BYTES/1024/1024), 
   MAX(SEGMENT_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY BYTES)  
FROM dba_segments 
WHERE SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE' 
GROUP BY tablespace_name;
```

Note, due to `SEGMENT_TYPE = 'TABLE'` your query will not include partitionized tables.

Another note, you will get only one table per tablespace in case several tables have exactly the same size. Use solution from APC in cause you need all tables.

Comment: This is wonderful solution what is  MAX(SEGMENT_NAME) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY BYTES)  do?

Comment: The solution does not do what you think it does. MAX(SEGMENT_NAME) returns the name of the last segment alphabetically, not the name of the biggest table.

Comment: @APC, I did not write max(segments_name), take care of "keep..." expression

Comment: Did you read linked documentation?  There you get explanation.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help!Is this pure sql or pl/sql?

Comment: I ran this query and it produced the wrong results. 12c. But it if works for you, that's fine

Answer (score 0):

Use Analytical function to rank table in order of size:

```
SELECT 
    tablespace_name,segment_name,tab_size_mb
FROM    
(
    SELECT
    tablespace_name,segment_name,bytes/1024/1024 tab_size_mb,
    RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY tablespace_name ORDER BY bytes DESC) AS rnk
    FROM dba_segments
    WHERE segment_type='TABLE'
)
WHERE rnk=1;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution .is rnk sql or pl/sql function.

Comment: Rank is pl/sql function.